# Samba share slow on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, windows, samba

I need some help as it is driving me crazy. I have created a Samba share on my Ubuntu 20.04 machine, but it is incredibly slow when browsing it from a Windows 10 machine. Especially loading image thumbs is slow.

Copying a file from the Samba share to a folder on my Windows 10 pc of about 10gb shows about 100 MB/sec and takes approx. 3 minutes (not that bad), however when testing readspeeds on the Ubuntu machine it shows x2:

```
root@xxx:~# sudo hdparm -Tt /dev/sda

/dev/sda:
 Timing cached reads:   25776 MB in  1.99 seconds = 12975.74 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads: 678 MB in  3.00 seconds = 225.72 MB/sec
```

I've tried setting "socket options = TCP_NODELAY" in smb.conf, but that doesn't make a difference.

Any ideas?

Comment: Network shares depend on the network more than anything else. I don't see a problem here.

Comment: I agree. Network is a factor. Going from/to ext to/from ntfs is also slow. I do not believe software is going to make it go quicker.

Comment: So you guys believe 100MB/s isn't that bad at all? Would you suggest changing to ntfs instead of using ext4?

Comment: Change what to ntfs? And I would generally say no -but- samba is about connecting Linix/ext to Windows/ntfs+fat. What part do you believe you can switch to ntfs?